# Easy interpretation of matrix multiplication with a set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have just started learning convex optimization. I am having little bit difficulties in some notations.

Currently I just encountered the following equation:
$$
\boldsymbol{epi}(wf) =  \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
I & 0 \\
0 & w
 \end{array} \right]\boldsymbol{epi}(f)
$$

where $w$ is positive and $f$ is convex. I have seen other matrix multiplications, but never encountered a matrix multiplication with a set, also how can I interpret it? Geometric interpretation would be helpful. Thanks.

[Book reference](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) page 79, 3.2.1 Nonnegative weighted sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation is quite fine. Let $X$ be a set and $f:X\rightarrow D$ a function defined on $X$. Then
\begin{equation}
f(X):=\{f(x)\in D: x\in X\}.
\end{equation}
To the proof:
Suppose $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The epigraph for $f$ is defined as
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Epi}(f):=\{(x,a)\in D\times\mathbb{R}: f(x)\leq a\}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, for $w\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Epi}(w\cdot f):=\{(x,a)\in D\times\mathbb{R}: w\cdot f(x)\leq a\}.
\end{equation}
Now, suppose we have $(x,a)\in \operatorname{Epi}(f),$ i.e. $f(x)\leq a$. Then
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}&0\\0&w
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x\\wa
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
meaning $(x,wa)\in \operatorname{Epi}(w\cdot f)$.

Comment: This only shows that RHS of the set equation in the question is a subset of the LHS. You still have the other inclusion to show.

Comment: The proof can be read in both directions...

Comment: Nope. This is not rigorous. As it stands, you've only shown one direction. If you're aware of this, then gr8 (let the OP do the other direction, for example); if not, then there is a problem...

Comment: why so aggressive, why such an argument "ad hominem"? You certainly mean "If you're NOT aware of this", right? The involved matrix is diagonal and therefore invertible,  so it is entirely analogous to the presented solution.

Answer (score 0):

The case $w = 0$ is obvious, and thus obmitted. For $w > 0$, let $D_w$ be the $(n+1)$-by-$(n+1)$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\underbrace{1,\ldots,1}_{n \text{ times}}$, $w$ respectively. Then, $$\text{epi}(wf) := \{(z, t) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} | wf(z) \le t\} = \{(z, w\tau) |  z \in \mathbb R^n, t\in \mathbb R, f(z) \le \tau\} = \{D_w[z\;\tau]^T | (z, \tau) \in \text{epi}(f)\} = D_w\text{epi}(f),$$
as claimed.

Comment: Sorry, I might lag some information. Can you please explain a little how 
$$
\{(z, t) \in \mathbb R^{n+1} | wf(z) \le t\} = \{(z, wt) |  z \in \mathbb R^n, t\in \mathbb R, f(z) \le t\}
$$ 
are equal?

Comment: Since $w > 0$, it holds that $wf(z) \le 1 \text{ iff } f(z) \le t/w$. Now do the change of variable $\tau = t / w$. I've made this more explicit in my answer.